# BLE takes too much time while sending data from iOS 7.1 to iOS 8

Tags: ios8, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios7.1, ios-bluetooth

I have a strange issue. I am developing an app in which I am sending **Chunks in 20-20 bytes.**.

Everything is working fine.

When I am sending Bytes data **from iOS 8 to iOS 8** device it take around 4-5 second to transfer from one device to another, but my problem is when I am sending Bytes data from **iOs 7.1 to iOs 8** or reverse, It take around 17-20 seconds to transfer the data from one device to any device.

**Why it's taking too much time in iOS 7.1 to iOS 8 or reverse?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254048/iphone-4s-ble-data-transfer-speed?rq=1

Comment: Thank you , Manthan, I ll update u soon for this.

Comment: Hello Manthan, Can u write your comment as answer so i can upvote and accept your ans bcz i got  so many thing from this/

Comment: Did you get solution from that link of your question?

Comment: Not perfect but ya gt some idea about it.

Comment: Then don't accept the answer until it is fully satisfied to you. Please post the correct solution of your answer when you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at some of the links below. That might help you.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254048/iphone-4s-ble-data-transfer-speed?rq=1)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140260/background-time-issue-for-bluetooth-le-app-for-iphone-4s?rq=1)

This is just a reference of links that might help you.

Credit goes to them for this answer.