# data not sending from ios 7 to ios 8 through bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I want to send data from IOS 7 device to IOS 8 device but the receiver device is not responding. But somehow same code is working for IOS 8 to IOS 7 transmission. Is there any permission required to get access from IOS 7 to IOS 8 device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492710/ble-takes-too-much-time-while-sending-data-from-ios-7-1-to-ios-8-transfer-spee/28493451#28493451